# Java Spring bean creation and access from external jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have spring jar for my entity beans created as export--java--JARfile, where i have beans defined as follows:

```
package com.my.beans;
@Component("expBean")
public class ExpBean {
}
```

I also have config in this jar

```
package com.my;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class pBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public ExpBean getExpBean() {
        return new ExpBean();
    }
}
```

I have client spring application where i am adding above jar having only beans as by external dependency and trying to get my beans when spring app starts using following code in main code in client spring app.

```java
package com.my;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication()
@ComponentScan("com.my")
public class Application {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {         
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
          WMyBean bean = (WMyBean) ctx.getBean("expBean");
          bean.doSomething();
}
}
```

But when checked the list of bean definition printed, i do not see my bean from external jar and also i get following error.

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'expBean' available"
```

I tried many options but not sure whats missing.
Option 1

```
@ComponentScan("com.my")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
```

Option 2

```
@ComponentScan({"com.my"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
```

Need valuable inputs on step that i am missing out.

Question 1: Is it mandatory for me to do config change in client project to access my dependent jar entities?

Question 2: Can it be dynamic, load all entities without configuration as @bean in client project config?

Question 3: Do i need to build client jar every-time i change my dependent jar file with more entities?

Thanks

Comment: If the bean is in a subpackage of your application, you don't need `ComponentScan`. `getExpBean()` will create a bean named `getExpBean`, while `Component("expBean")` will create a bean named `expBean`, and having both is an error for singleton instances since one will override the other.

Comment: 1. try `ctx.getBean("getExpBean")` (?) 2. alternatively: `@Impot(pBeanConfig.class)` (and *no* (additional) `@ComponentScan` ) 3. alternatively try `@ComponentScan("com.my.beans")` (leaving the name `expBean` ...)

Comment: can you add your maven pom.xml of each jar?

Answer (score 0):

First I am assuming the build tool is Gradle, but you can import the jar as a local file like this for the sake of experiment:

```
dependencies {
implementation files('libs/something_local.jar')}
```

Then, assuming you use Eclipse you can right click the project folder and do a 'Gradle refresh'

In your config class you can either autowire in the bean for the class as a whole , or choose to create it whenever an instance of the class is created by declaring it within the class constructor:

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

//I also have config in this jar

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class pBeanConfig {

    //Autowire in the bean for the whole class.
    @Autowired
    ExpBean expBean;
    
    public pBeanConfig() {
    
    //Or, you may want to have a bean instance whenever the pBeanConfig class is instantiated.
    ExBean exBean;
   }
}
```

I'm making a number of assumptions for this answer like it's a Gradle project, but you can set up a similar dependency for Maven by modifying the POM file to include that file.

Build tools aside, in Eclipse you can simply add the jar file by right clicking the project and build path => configure build path => add external jar file.

UPDATE:
This pic describes how I set up the bean within a separate jar file via eclipse. The steps should show that the bean can be reached with this project even though it's in a jar and not in the project itself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have already added my bean jar as dependency and trying to see in my client using the above sample, if i have my dependent beans loaded in context.
But i am getting the error mentioned in question above for the same and do not see beans in beandefination printed in main.

Comment: I have the same project set up in Eclipse just as you wrote it , and I can see the bean appear in the list when I output the names. Would it help if I gave you a link to my project via Git so you can set it up?

Comment: Yes that would really help me to understand what i have missed.

Comment: I am using Maven

Comment: This is a Gradle project, the dependencies in build.gradle shows what would be pulled in via Maven POM.xml. It's Spring 2.6.2 . Just import as a gradle project and run. https://github.com/MikeT2424/Spring-scrap.git

Comment: Thanks for reply, After going through code, i found that you have both beans in same app. actually my question is about 2 separate projects. I have 1 project which has only beans and i have 2nd project where i put dependency on bean jar and trying to find how can i load those beans in 2nd project. It would be good if you can help

Comment: Rather than say it here I added a pic to show what I did to import the bean via a jar file in this project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response, i tried to get your sample project from git on my local and test it out, but as its gradle (i am new to it) and not maven i faced issues.  Just want to request you to provide sample project on Maven, so that i can compare it with mine and understand where am i going wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response, i m able to see the bean now after adding following lines in my BeanConfig.java in client project : 
public WPurchaseOrder getPO() {
 return new WPurchaseOrder();
}
This leaves me with following 3 Question : 
1. is it mandatory for me to do that change in client project to access my entities?
2. can it be dynamic, load all entities without configuration as @bean in client project config?
3. do i need to compile client jar everytime i change my dependent jar file with more entities?